# html canvas zindex

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fabricjs

How do I change the zindex of an element inside a canvas?

Example code:

```
fabric.Image.fromURL('http://nocookie.net/bw.jpg', function(image) {
    image.set('left', 200).set('top', 250);
    canvas.add(image);
});


var helloWorld = new fabric.Text('Hello world!', { 
  left: 0, 
  top: 0,
  fontfamily: 'delicious_500',
  zindex: 10
});

canvas.add(helloWorld);
```

Using the fabric.js library.

For future reference:

fabric.Element.html#bringForward

Comment: Can you post an example? [Do you really have an element *in* the canvas?](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Guwvwp0uSU8)

Comment: @sdleihssirhc posted some sample code to show what i mean. i want to be able to set the text above the image.

Comment: Wow, the [fabric.js docs](http://kangax.github.com/fabric.js/docs/) are kind of useless.

Comment: @sdleihssirhc from what i understand you set it with object.set() problem is I don't know what property to set. :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't get the dang thing working at all, but here's my guess as to what's happening:

1. Fabric asks that URL for the image. Fabric has been given a callback method when the image is returned, so while it's waiting, it moves on to the next task
2. Fabric creates the Text object and adds it to the canvas.
3. Finally, it notices that the image has loaded (the specific example you provided actually 404'd on me), and passes it to the callback method.

Because the image is added to the canvas *after* the text, I'm assuming that Fabric is acting just as the canvas normally would: things that are added later are drawn on top of things that are already there. ...Even though you gave the text a z-index.

Remember, I couldn't get it to work and just gave up. So it's entirely possible I'm totally, completely wrong. If that is the case, I have another theory:

Are you sure that `zindex` is the correct property? If you are, then try setting it on the image, as well:

```
image.set('left', 200).set('top', 250).set('zindex', 5);
```

And if you *aren't* sure, then... there you go.

Comment: Well zindex is just a random guess. Tried zIndex as well to no avail. No idea what the real property is. I did try setting the image as well. Thank you for your help +1, i tried looking up the canvas api on google but no go. :(

Comment: @mark What about my first idea? Try declaring `helloWorld` before the image, and then adding it to the canvas after you've added the image. (That is, move `canvas.add(helloWorld)` so that it's *inside* the image function.)

Comment: That did the trick! yay thanks! Sorry I didn't understand what you meant the first time you said it. :P Unfortunately still have not figured out the api command for canvas zindex, so the question title currently is a bit misleading.  But it solves my current problem so big thank you

Comment: @mark Yeah, as I was rereading my answer, I realized I pointed out that that may be the problem, but didn't actually say how to fix it. Whoops. Alls well that ends well.

Answer (score 1):

Since fabric.js version 1.1.4 a new method for zIndex manipulation is available:

```
canvas.moveTo(object, index);
object.moveTo(index);
```

i hope this is what you want:

http://jsfiddle.net/Kienz/RRv3g/